# How to run a test class more than once in a single suite in testng

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a suite setup in testng for selenium.  This suite includes the same test class twice since that class has to be run two times as modifications were made in between.  The problem I'm having is testng is only running the first occurrence of the class, and not the second occurrence.  Is there a way to get it to run both times in the same suite?

```
<suite name="P0-SuiteLoopbackGenerateUnsignedItemAgreementToNLC" parallel="false" verbose="10">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.bpms.tests.MySuiteListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <test name="FirefoxTest">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
        <parameter name="debug" value="true"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.PerformLogisticsAnalysis"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.SecondReview"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewNLCDiagrams"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConfirmItemSpecifications"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.LoopbackGenerateUnsignedItemAgreementToNLC"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.DetermineLoopbackToNLC"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.PerformLogisticsAnalysisAfterLoopback"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.SecondReview"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.ReviewNLCDiagrams"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.ConsolidateCountryAuthorizations"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.FinalizeItemInformationAndGenerateUnsignedItemAgreementPDF"/>
            <class name="com.bpms.tests.VerifyAndUploadItemDocuments"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Running this suite results in the second "SecondReview and ReviewNLCDiagrams" being skipped.  I need these to run the second time.  Is there a way?

Comment: what is the point of running the same Test classe twice in the same test suite? Remember changes made to your java class need to be compiled for the test class to consider them.

Comment: Have you tried something like `public class SecondReviewAgain extends SecondReview {}`?

Comment: You can group the first 7 testcases in one group and last 5 in another group. and then run the groups through testng.

Comment: The purpose of running the same test class in the same suite is this...  Each of the test classes are basically testing a single webpage of a process flow.  Sometimes, we run one page, then another which changes the values that were verified in the previous page.  Thus I need to re-run the same test class that was previously run to verify the data that was changed actually took effect.

Comment: @chrylis  This idea of public class SecondReviewAgain extends SecondReview {} intrigues me. Can you give me an example?

Comment: That was the entire example. Try declaring that class and then listing it in the suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is TestNG is designed to not allow duplicate classes in the xml.  Taking the suggestions, I had to create new classes (dummy classes) that do nothing more than extend the real class.  The solved the problem.